# Why can't I add a bounty to this question?

Tags: support, bounty

I've asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/297959/how-do-you-check-how-much-power-a-usb-port-can-deliver) a few days ago, and while Jeff's answer is pretty cool, it doesn't really answer my question. So I'd like to add a bounty to maximize the chances of getting a good answer. I thought the requirement was that the question has to be two days old - is there another one that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I like this question enough that I'm going to put a bounty on it myself, actually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an existing open bounty on this question:

[How to mount via cifs non-unicode samba sever with character set conversion?](https://superuser.com/questions/206121/how-to-mount-via-cifs-non-unicode-samba-sever-with-character-set-conversion)

The current bounty system is such that you can have only one active bounty at a time

Comment: You can have *three* active bounties at a time now.

Answer (score 6):

You can only have one bounty active at a time.

It currently seems you have a bounty live on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/206121/how-to-mount-via-cifs-non-unicode-samba-sever-with-character-set-conversion) question.

Once that bounty has been awarded or expires, you will be able to activate another one.

---

References you might find useful:

- The FAQ's [bounty section](https://superuser.com/faq#bounty).
- Meta.SO's FAQ question for [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).